# Getting Lightbox to Appear over Referring Page

Tags: asp.net, lightbox, master-pages

I am working in ASP.NET (framework 2.0) with Master Pages.

I have a page that requires registration and then the user gets kicked back to the referring page.

I need to figure out how to provide a success lightbox that appears over the referring page, not the registration page (the event is fired on form submit).

I have the inline stuff in the master page and the scripts and everything fires just fine but the form is refreshed with the new (referring) page and the DIV gets hidden again.

Is sessions the only way to go here? Is there a way of having one lightbox appearing from the master page regardless of what the sub-pages are doing?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use querystring parameter and check it in refering page. or master page.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a successful registration event. Can you emit some javascript in that scenario that would cause a redirection to the referring page. You could pass a parameter which would indicate that a light box should show up. I don't think you can redirect directly from successful registration because I am guessing that some cookie would need to be set- which the framework should handle. I might be off, but that is where I would start. I would try and avoid Session if possible.